# Form validation in function views

Tags: django

Is there any difference between the 2 parts of code?

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title') #<<--
            print(title)
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/test.html', {'form': form})



def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            title = request.POST.get('title') # <<--
            print(title)
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/test.html', {'form': form})
```

Since both cases is part of form.is_valid() condition I believe it should be same right?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not necessary produce same result as [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) documentation states

> Each field in a Form class is responsible not only for validating
> data, but also for “cleaning” it – normalizing it to a consistent
> format. This is a nice feature, because it allows data for a
> particular field to be input in a variety of ways, always resulting in
> consistent output.

Comment: Thanks for that. Based on your experience should I in general always access data through the cleaned_data attribute and avoid altogether the request.POST even though when  the data is valid?